# Windows 8 downgrade to windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, downgrade

I have just bought a Lenovo Ideapad Z585 which has Windows 8 pre installed. I don't think it is the Pro version as there is no sticker on the case with the product key. I have spent 36 hours trying to get WIFI working to no avail. Trying windows update (which was suggested as a cure to the WIFI issue) fails everytime and despite following all of the suggestions/guidance/advice I have found on line I cannot sort the fault out.

I don't have the time or the expertise and need my machine for University so I want to change the OS.

I appreciate I will have to spend some money so can someone please, please tell me what to do.

Comment: If you have "just bought" this product, surely you can take it back to the store or return it to the online store, for a full refund if it is not possible for you to get WiFi to work.

Comment: Please verify which edition exactly you have.  You do understand you will have to purchase a Windows 7 license right?  The best way is to go ahead and purchase Windows 7, boot into the Windows Installer, and wipe the hdd. You **CANNOT** use the existing license you have, an Windows 7 OEM license **CANNOT** be transfered to another pc.

Comment: "I don't think it is the Pro version as there is no sticker on the case with the product key." - That's the case with all new Win8 PCs, not just Core or Pro.

Comment: Microsoft... :(

Answer (score 1):

This may affect your warranty etc, so I suggest you are sure you want to proceed.

There could also be hardware compatibility issues with W7 (IMO not likely but not impossible).

I suggest you Google a term like "how to install windows 7 from scratch".

HOWEVER, it could be the wireless card/adapter is faulty. I suggest you rule that out first. Try and connect to a different router, only test on a router you know that works and if it is new, send it back to the shop! There are many posts here on SU which help explain what steps can be taken to debug wireless networking issues.

Comment: Its not just about WIFI. I have it connected via Ethernet at the moment and still have problems with the update process. I have tried so many different ways to sort out these problems and am at my wits end. I am satisfied that there would be no compatibility issues and hardware is working OK.

Comment: I have a Windows 7 Home Edition DVD that came with the PC I used previously, can I install that? Would there be issues activating it?

Comment: @Jack This now sounds more like a permissions issue. When you open the Windows Update window, instead of clicking the button Check for updates, underneath is a text link "check online for updates with Microsoft update) and see if the same error persists. As for licensing agreements, you'll need to read the EULA but providing the license isn't in use else where, then I believe it is fine.

Comment: @daverock I tried to update a hp625 from Windows 7 to 8. Extremly slow wifi afterwards, googled , tried 2 weeks - and finally installed 7 again. No problems afterwards. Windows 8 seems to have some problems with for example releases of dlink 625 (and other routers). that is number one. Number 2 you will find in some forum that update does not work. 2 independend problems. Both prevented me from using 8.

Comment: @Offler - Thanks, this is good to know, but I wonder, as per your comments, whether buying a new wireless router *could* be a cheaper solution (I know OP has a W7 copy but if OP didn't have W7 then it could be an answer). Thank you Offler, very helpful comment! Could be a nice interim solution while things get fixed although if it is a W8 issue, then it is very poor!

Comment: @DaveRook - Except the author doesn't have a license he can actually use.  The license he has is an OEM license connected to his other OEM pc.  **Furthermore Windows 8 can't have compatability issues with routers that just not possible.**

Comment: @Ramhound He has a disc which came with the previous PC, I would assume (and yes, it is an assumption) that would mean a sticker on the case with the serial (or is this not a legal way to use the license?). I agree that the connection issue may not be related to W8 but, it can by the network adapter. There are a few posts here on SU where it appears it is a conflict between adapters/routers. As always, good comments, thanks.

Comment: Guys all of your suggestions whilst appreciated have changed nothing. I have just spoken to Microsoft who advised I can downgrade using an existing W7 DVD and product key that I have. I also spoke to Lenovo who confirmed all hardware is OK. Downgrade it is. Is it wrong to assume after spending so much money, that this should just work out of the box?

Comment: @Jack, of course these things should just work, you have been unlucky. The point I am trying to make is, what if the fault is with your wireless adapter is faulty (ie, broken hardware). If this is the case then no OS will fix it, and I'm trying to save you the time :).. The fact MS advised a downgrade does comply with Offlers comments. I also didn't realise the license covered you for a downgrade. I wonder if this is all W8 or just certain licenses.

Comment: @DaveRook - It sounds like he has an OEM HP Windows 7 license this cannot be used on his Lenovo laptop.  Lenovo would need to provide him the required license to downgrade his Lenovo Windows 8 license

Comment: @ramhound Compatibility issues may be the wrong word, but people here have problems with dlink series router revisions which are locked by a provider (no update, only pw change possible). Also the same occurs with android ICS and dlink 615 (there are a hell lot of questions if you search the internet for "dlink 615 ics" - not all get them to work even if all other (non ICS/Windows 8) devices work. Same is applicable for other routers. Sometimes it works to turn wifi N off. SO- in most cases there are specific routers with does not work with specific os. Wouldn't you name that incompatible?

Comment: @Offler - I would call that people who have no bloody idea what they are doing trying to solve a problem they don't understand.  I have the same router, and a laptop with a N adapater, and I never had a problem.

Comment: @ramhound : yes, and now try it with a frimware from last year and a device without N support ;-) Statistics are always right (he my 98SE never had a bluescreen - does a bluescreen not exist?)

Comment: @Offler - Why would I use a router and not upgrade its firmware?  I am just saying all routers that supports 802.11N support 802.11N adapaters.  If there is a problem its the adapater that causes the problem not the router.

Comment: @ramhound: Please read again: we have here for example provider looked routers. Please also read in a search engine of your choice of problems with ICS and router. From 2006 (During 3 years) N devices were sold, but N was officially first releases 2009. N is not a standard which is so good as you might think. If you can also take the same adapter and just use a different OS and then everything works you really need to rethink to blame a adapter. Easier:  If you look at an android tablet you normally have only few parameters. Same configuration with 2.3 and 4.0 and 2.3 works and 4.0 doesn't.

Comment: Same with Windows 8, only you have a hell lot more parameters then with android where you can try, but in the end you will see that some devices won't work together with the firmware of some routers. Oh, also in prof. networks you can encounter strange problems mixing Cisco and 3Com switches. The problems should not be there -  but sadly they still are.

Comment: @Offler - Don't need to read again.  802.11N actually is a standard.  I will repeat that the problem isn't with Windows 8, Windows 8 does not care what 801.11 standard you connect to, thats entirely up to the adapter.

Comment: @Ramhound networking is one of the points which is reworked in Windows 8. Therfore you can get everything from "Windows couldn't automatically bind the IP protocol stack to the network adapter." (so forget the pure adapter thing) to compatibility issues with drivers and so on. Hardware is really the most seldom thing which fails in networking with Windows 8.

Comment: @Offler - Your logic makes no sense, but since this is a discussion at this point, lets just drop it.